# Pandas: How to change the structure of a DataFrame by inserting rows with blank values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't quite know how to explain my problem simply
but I need to modify a `DataFrame` by inserting almost empty rows
for a software formatting compatibility problem.

Here an example:

I need to change this type of `Dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"line1": [200, 400, 800], 
                   "line2": [400, 900, 700], 
                   "line3": [800, 700, 966], 
                   "name": ["bla", "bloo", "bloom"})
print df

   line1  line2  line3   name
0    200    400    800    bla
1    400    900    700   bloo
2    800    700    966  bloom
```

To something like this:

```
   line_name  line1  line2  line3
0  ID
1  name 
2  bla        200     400    800 
3  bloo       400     900    700
4  bloom      800     700    966
```

Of course the real dataframe have much more rows and columns.
So I'm looking for a method that can deal with a variable number of columns without having to manually adding the "Blank" under the line columns one by one.

I tried some `Groupby` methods as well as making 2 dataframes ( one with just the `line`, `ID`, `name` structure and another with the actual `names` and `values` and then merging them but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try solution with [Setting With Enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"line1": [200, 400, 800],
                   "line2": [400, 900, 700], 
                   "line3": [800, 700, 966], 
                   "name": ["bla", "bloo", "bloom"]})
print df

   line1  line2  line3   name
0    200    400    800    bla
1    400    900    700   bloo
2    800    700    966  bloom
#create empty lists with last item name and ID by length of dataframe
#add to df two lines
df.loc[-1] = [np.nan for i in range(df.shape[1] - 1) ] + ['name']
df.loc[-2] = [np.nan for i in range(df.shape[1] - 1) ] + ['ID']
print df

    line1  line2  line3   name
 0    200    400    800    bla
 1    400    900    700   bloo
 2    800    700    966  bloom
-1    NaN    NaN    NaN   name
-2    NaN    NaN    NaN     ID

#sort and reset index, rename column and fill nan to empty string
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'name':'line_name'}).fillna('')
#reorder columns
df = df[['line_name','line1','line2','line3']]
```

```
print df

  line_name line1 line2 line3
0        ID                  
1      name                  
2       bla   200   400   800
3      bloo   400   900   700
4     bloom   800   700   966
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is exactly what you want. Based on the example dataframe given, you could try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"line1": [200, 400, 800], "line2": [400, 900, 700], "line3": [800, 700, 966], "name": ["bla", "bloo", "bloom"]})
dftemp=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
dftemp.loc[0]=(len(df.columns)-1)*['']+['ID']
dftemp.loc[1]=(len(df.columns)-1)*['']+['name']
dfnew= dftemp.append(df,ignore_index=True)
dfnew.rename(columns={'name':'line_name'}, inplace=True)
cols = dfnew.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-1:]+cols[:-1]
dfnew = dfnew[cols]
print(dfnew)

Output:
      line_name line1 line2 line3
0        ID                  
1      name                  
2       bla   200   400   800
3      bloo   400   900   700
4     bloom   800   700   966
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"line1": [200, 400, 800], "line2": [400, 900, 700], "line3": [800, 700, 966], "name": ["bla", "bloo", "bloom"]}) df.loc[-1] = [np.nan for i in range(df.shape[1] - 1) ] + ['name'] df.loc[-2] = [np.nan for i in range(df.shape[1] -1)] + ['ID'] df = df.fillna('') df=df.sort_index() df=df.reset_index() df.loc[:,['name','line1','line2','line3']]
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)